# Hacker News Android Client: "Cannot resolve symbol 'MainActivity_'"

Tags: android

I'm currently working on a fork of the [Hacker News](https://github.com/manmal/hn-android) Android client to implement a pull-down refresh feature for the news feed. However, after I imported the project from Github to Android Studio, I get the following error:

[Cannot resolve symbol 'MainActivity_'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gJHa.png)

for not only MainActivity but also for several other activities used by the app. This error makes sense because if you look in the project directory, none of the activity names end in an underscore "_". However, these activities are referenced with the underscore in the Android Manifest. This leads me to think that I somehow imported the project into Android Studio incorrectly, but I'm really not sure.

Yesterday I was able to resolve this issue with Build > Clean Project, and then Build > Rebuild Project. However, today I reopened the project, the same issues arise, and these actions no longer fix the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: So under Gradle the AndroidAnnotations library; which the Hacker News client uses; relies on an annotation processor in order to do it's thing to generate the `MainActivity_` class you are seeing reference to. I am unsure of the specifics of the android-apt plugin which manages this process, but have you changed the package name that you are using in the manifest file, or any of the packages in your source code?

Answer (score 1):

You should `AndroidAnnotations library` in the project.

For this configuration, please refer to [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Configuration).